# Botón no cambia de color en Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Estoy aprendiendo a usar Android Studio y me encuentro usando un RelativeLayout. He insertado un botón pero cuando intento cambiarle el color usando background no pasa nada, sigue en el color con el que apareció por defecto.
[image: Captura]

este es mi código

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
    android:layout_width="127dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editTextTextPersonName6"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextTextPersonName6"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_marginStart="232dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="-117dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Button"
    android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Comment: `@android:color/holo_green_light` que valor tiene? intenta cambiar a un color manualmente, tipo `@color/black`

Comment: Ya cambie a color/black y el color sigue en purpura

Comment: El problema es, sino me equivoco que estas usando un `style` predeterminado en el diseño de la interfaz. Lo que yo suelo hacer es quitar la línea del `style`. Avisa si te funciona :)